# Select vector by string pattern

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a lot of vectors loaded and I want to select them by their name. For example: vector name is `a_b` and `a_c`, within a function I do sth like 
`name <- paste0('a','_','b')`. How can I do that in R?

Comment: In theory you can do that with `get()` but that's not really something that is recommended. How did all these variables get created in the first place? If you have a bunch of related variables with information in their names, its much easier to work with then as a named list of values in R. So it's probably worth taking a step back to look how you got into this problem in the first place.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks!